# How to install LeapDroid Android Emulator?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I recently heard about LeapDroid Android Emulator, so I want to install it in my Ubuntu 16.04. How can I install this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is only for Windows, it requires direct x, you can try with Wine but IDK if it will work http://www.leapdroid.com/download.php

Comment: Apparently the Linux version is being worked on; see http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=67470735&postcount=7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, we did all development on Linux, for each build, we make Leapdroid to work first on Linux, then build for Windows. What is missing is the packaging which we are working on right now. We should release a Linux version late in August.

Thanks,

(I am a member of the Leapdroid Team)

Comment: Okay thank you for the reply. I am waiting for Linux version of Leapdroid :) and release Linux version as soon as possible. Good luck

Comment: It is October now, is the linux version ready?

Comment: Yeah I ended up here while searching for an update.  Any news on the linux version?  Anxious to try it out

Answer (score 2):

LeapDroid has discontinued its user support recently. Evidently, they are developing a new version of this emulator under Google. There's an official announcement on [LeapDroid's official site](http://www.leapdroid.com/).

> ## Announcement
>
> We started to develop LeapDroid emulator in 2015. It took us more than one year of hard work to build a fast Android emulator.
>
> Today, we're excited to announce the next phase of our journey -- we are joining Google. While it's too soon to comment on specific plans, we look forward to working with our new colleagues at Google to continue pushing the frontier of technology.
>
> In order to focus on our next chapter, **we have decided to discontinue the development of LeapDroid emulator**. However, if you have LeapDroid already installed, you can continue to use it. Please review the User FAQ for more information.
>
> We want to personally thank the amazing community of Android developers and users who have inspired us since day one. We’ve been so proud to build LeapDroid, and can’t wait to show you more of what we’ll be working on at Google.